# Code iOS scrollbars to workaround Bootstrap 4 Carousel Bug: Click/Tap causes additional unwanted swipes

Tags: javascript, ios, bootstrap-4, carousel, hammer.js

## The issue & environment

Running **Bootstrap 4 from CDN** and there is currently a **known bug** affecting the **Carousel** on **iOS devices** for which a fix [github #28558](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/28558) is devised, but still pending i.e. **NOT** as yet released. Fix was introduced back on 27 March but unfortunately we are still awaiting Bootstrap v4.4.0, which contains the fix, for which there is sadly **NO** release date yet.

​

### A brief summary of the cause

After **SWIPE** carousel on iOS devices, Bootstrap's `carousel.js` doesn't currently reset an internal Bootstrap parameter (touchDeltaX) and hence any **subsequent taps** or **clicks** will result in further **unwanted swipes**.

​

### The proposed fix

We noticed that any **vertical touch gesture** which **invokes the scrollbars** seems to somehow **reset this unwanted action** and hence it should pave the way forward for a workaround.

I initially suspected this should be quite straight forward, possibly just a single line of code.  However the reality is that I'm stuck and can't seem to figure out how to do this, move the srollbars programmatically on iOS devices :(

Attempts to use `window.scrollBy(0,1);` and `window.scrollBy(0,-1);` to move scrollbars back and forth doesn't seem to work on iOS devices, although srollBy seems to work fine in our test desktop environment but not on our iOS devices.

```
  function scrollY() {
    if (hasTouchscreen){
       window.scrollBy(0,1);
       window.scrollBy(0,-1);
     }
  }
```

**I've created a CodePen** (see below) to **showing our reduced test case**, but for some reason our code needed to be tweaked slightly to work inside the CodePen and even though it still isn't working 100% like in our dev/test environments (i.e. not playing embedded video using control buttons) using our larger desktop devices. However it does work on iOS which is the main reason for our reduced test case and it clearly shows the bug we are trying to implement a workaround for, so the CodePen below is fit for our purpose.

​

### How to reproduce the issue (iOS)

Try to use the **PLAY/PAUSE/STOP** buttons we added, followed by the **PREV/NEXT** carousel buttons (**NOT swiping!**) and then the **PLAY/PAUSE/STOP** buttons again. It should all work just fine.

Now repeat the above and instead of using the **PREV/NEXT** buttons use a swipe left or swipe right touch gesture on the iOS screen to move the carousel. Afterwards try to press the **PLAY/PAUSE/STOP** buttons again (or tap/click anywhere) and you will notice it forces another **UNWANTED** swipe in the last direction.

​

### The "manual" workaround (which works!)

The reason I am confident that a vertical gesture/scroll will provide us with a workaround is because this:

After **SWIPE LEFT/RIGHT**, try to **SWIPE UP/DOWN** (vertical gesture) so that you notice the scrollbars light up temporarily. Now when you click or tap anywhere on the screen it won't force another swipe and the **PLAY/PAUSE/STOP** buttons work as before.

However this is only a manual workaround for demonstration purposes as it's **not acceptable** from a user point of view **in the live environment**!

​

### Tried so far

Right at the end of the JS section there is a `function scrollY()` which does a `window.scrollBy(0,1);` and a `window.scrollBy(0,-1);` to try to move the scrollbars and even though this seems to work in our test environment it doesn't appear to affect the iOS scrollbars.

**NB** You can tell the code works in our test environment as a **SWIPE** not only moves on to the next slide it also **lights up** the **scrollbars temporarily** whereas using the **PREV/NEXT** buttons will **NOT** light up the scrollbars!

​​**Oh and of course I've searched StackOverflow etc for a solution but unfortunately nothing I looked at seem to work and I've not been able to work out how to do this :(**

​

## [ Code & req result ]

### CodePen:

[Bootstrap carousel with embedded YouTube videos + control buttons & touchswipe](https://codepen.io/magicmb/full/WNepERd)

​

**NB** As mentioned previously this CodePen **works** perfectly on **iOS devices**, but the **PLAY/PAUSE/STOP** buttons don't seem to work on our test Desktop environment for some reason even though `callPlayer()` function seems to invoke the video temporarily, but we're not bothered by this as it only seems to be an issue in CodePen (not our test environment) and it does work as expected on iOS devices which the test is meant for.

​

### Required result

Get the iOS **scrollbars to move programatically** (back & forth) which should **trigger a reset** of an internal Bootstrap param (touchDeltaX), thereby circumventing the existing bug present in the current Bootstrap `carousel.js` code and providing a workaround until Bootstrap v4.4.0 (or v5) is released.

Comment: More than a month after my post and Bootstrap v4.4.0 is still unavailable even though they seem to be in their final stages on their GitHub project.

The thing is: Even **after v.4.4.0 is released** and my issue is resolved, I still want to know **how to programatically use the scroll bars in iOS** irrelevant of the above issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap v4.4.0 was finally released and has fixed the issue.

In any case it would have been nice to find out how to programatically move the scrollbars in iOS, so if someone wants to comment on this please do so even though I'm closing this off now.